# InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database

Has anyone encountered this error using SQL Server 2005 and Data access application blocks in a failover configuration?

"InvalidOperationException Framework Data Provider Error 6"

It seems to occur in our server application at irregular intervals and more frequently when SQL Server is in failover config?   While doing some research I see that MS released a patch in .NET 2.0 sp1, however, the patch was not rolled forward or bundled in the lastest .NET service pack and we are reluctant to implement it if future service packs will overwrite it.

Our server is currently implemented using .NET 3.5 sp1 with the latest MS Data access application blocks.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've run into this error a bit, myself. Can anyone confirm whether 3.5 SP1 fixes this or, at the very least, won't interfere with the 2.0 SP1 hotfix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone is interested...

I does appear the MS have a [fix for this issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951847) in .NET 3.5 sp1 KB article 944099.    If you had applied the previous 2.0 fix then upgraded to 3.5 your patch would have been overwritten with a faultly System.Data.dll.  At least that seems to be what has happened in our case.

We have been running our system for nearly a week now with the patched server and so far so good.

Answer (score 0):

I Google'd around a bit and found some folks that fixed the problem by replacing the network cables going to their database server.  These types of errors are tough - do you have a Microsoft support contract?

Comment: Yeah... I saw that one too... made me laugh out loud actually.(but we replaced the cables anyway and still no luck) 
 We do have a Microsoft support contract, but I thought that id just check here before I log an issue with them.